# PHP 5.6 Vulnerability CVE-2018-7584

Tags: php, security, lamp, production-environment, php-5.6

We are using PHP 5.6.33 with CentOS in production environment. We found that PHP is having following vulnerability CVE-2018-7584. On the official page it is showing following :

> In PHP through 5.6.33, 7.0.x before 7.0.28, 7.1.x through 7.1.14, and
>   7.2.x through 7.2.2, there is a stack-based buffer under-read while parsing an HTTP response in the php_stream_url_wrap_http_ex function
>   in ext/standard/http_fopen_wrapper.c. This subsequently results in
>   copying a large string.

References :
https://www.cvedetails.com/cve-details.php?t=1&cve_id=CVE-2017-7679
https://www.exploit-db.com/exploits/44846/

It seems PHP 7.2 is also having same vulnerability. Is there any solution or workaround for this ?

Comment: here is the patch https://github.com/php/php-src/commit/523f230c831d7b33353203fa34aee4e92ac12bba

Comment: @BilalAhmed : Thanks for the answer. But my concern is, Should we change this directly to PHP source file ? What is the path for PHP source files in linux.

Answer (score 2):

> Is there any solution or workaround for this ?

Short-term solution: `sudo yum --security upgrade`

Long-term solution: [Automatic security upgrades](https://serversforhackers.com/c/automatic-security-updates-centos) so you don't give yourself alert fatigue.

If CentOS proper isn't giving you the latest security patches for PHP (like they're supposed to be doing), use Remi's repository instead, which provides [5.6.38](https://blog.remirepo.net/post/2018/09/14/PHP-version-5.6.38-7.0.32-7.1.22-and-7.2.10) as of this writing.